# Running Drupal in subfolder - stop access to URL example.com/subfolder/index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7

For various reasons regarding this site's host, we are running a Drupal 7 site inside a subfolder "live" so the path to D7 is /home/username/public_html/live/

To get the Drupal 7 site to load from the subfolder, we have the .htaccess below in /home/username/public_html and it works great.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ live/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/live%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* live/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* live/index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]
```

However, if I type https://website.com/live/index.php, the home page of the site loads and the URL in the location bar does not mask to https://website.com. A previous problem with a different rewrite rule caused other visitors to have reached this page and this has caused https://website.com/live/index.php to be included in our Google Analytics statistics.

Is there a way to rewrite .htaccess rules to avoid https://website.com/live/index.php being visible from now on? The .htaccess at /home/username/public_html/live is the default D7 .htaccess.

Comment: Check the original REQUEST_URI using a RewriteCond, and if that is `/live/index.php`, then make an external redirect.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Are you able to spell out how those rules would look? I have no htaccess experience

Comment: Have you tried looking at manuals? Given the answer by @CBroe, you should be able to find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to add another .htaccess file inside the /live folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+\/live/index\.php\s+ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```